# What is the best way to take animations from Maya to Blender?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, .fbx, alembic

In our studio the animations are done in Maya and they are rendered in blender Eevee.  Eevee saves a lot of time in rendering but the time is wasted in setting up the files for render. Right now we convert the files into alembic to take them into blender (Fbx format is not suited for this because somehow the fbx coming from maya does not work properly in blender). but the problem with alembic format is that we have to texture the character every time we take it into blender. Suppose there are 16 files for an episode in maya. So we have to take 16 different alembic files and open them in 16 different blender files and texture the characters 16 different times.
If anyone out there can tell a way to speed up things then that would be really helpful.

Comment: Alembic for *meshes*, FBX for *armatures*. The only thing you can do is writing scripts to optimize your "pipeline" eg. trying to recreate the shader tree from arnold. However, takes time as well.

Comment: So we need a guy who can write scripts for us?

Comment: That's the way studios handle such issues for decades... paying a *Technical Director* to create a so called *pipeline*.

Comment: Related or dupe: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)